# Why models are so big when imported into Unity ?Similarly canvas is too big?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

after I import models into unity when tested in real world is huge.The canvas when compared to the huge model is many times huge in unity editor.Since the **screen-space** of the canvas is given as **Overlay** no problem arises.When I want to place a **text inside a canvas in world-space** the problem arises.For that when I try to create canvas it must be really small values like width =1 and height =2.It is so small that I cannot add a text into it.The text becomes so small and blur.I cannot increase the size of the models as they become huge in real world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quirk of Unity which you have to get used to. Unity doesn't specify unity of distance, and 1 unit can represent different sizes.

Canonical interpretation is 1m for 3d objects, and 1pixel for UI. As the default UI defaults to screenspace, you'll get a canvas that is almost two kilometeres long (for HD), if you assume a box is 1x1x1m.

The easiest way to place world UI in a useful way is to scale it down, I typically use 0.001 scale for worldspace canvases, which gives a real world pixel size of 1mm.

As far as imported models go, the root cause is generally the same - other 3D packages might not be the metric scale, which results a difference in scale that needs to be corrected. If you have acces to the 3D package used to produce the content its best to just set it to use meteres before exporting the mesh

Comment: How to add text to that small canvas in world space

Comment: the canvas internally will have a specified resolution, so when you focus your screne view to it (press F while having the canvas selected) you can work in an identical way to when the canvas is big

Comment: I made the canvas say width=3 and height =3 when i add a text as child to that canvas the text is really big.When i scale down the text it becomes blur

Comment: make the canvas 1920x1080, and just scale it down to desired width. You can also try the Canvas Scaler component